# Update a df by looking up values but keep original if look up df doesn't have any value in the original df

Tags: r

I have X df like this:

```
> x <- data.frame("count" = (12:14), "X"=c("a","No","b"), "Y"=c("b","c","Yes"), "Z"=c("c","c","c"), "R"=c("b","No","a"))
> x
  count  X   Y Z  R
1    12  a   b c  b
2    13 No   c c No
3    14  b Yes c  a
```

and a look up Y df like this:

```
> y <- data.frame("Key"=c("a","b","c"), "Value"=c("AT","BT","CT"))
> y
  Key Value
1   a    AT
2   b    BT
3   c    CT
```

I want to search key value from Y and fill it up in X so that final df would look like this:(If the look up table doesn't have value such as Yes,NO keep those value)

```
> df.final
  count  X   Y  Z  R
1    12 AT  BT CT BT
2    13 No  CT CT No
3    14 BT Yes CT AT
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `tidyverse` functions. You can reshape your first dataframe to long, then join with `y` and finally adjust the variable `Value`. After that you can reshape to wide in order to get the expected result:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Data
x <- data.frame("count" = (12:14), "X"=c("a","No","b"), "Y"=c("b","c","Yes"),
                "Z"=c("c","c","c"), "R"=c("b","No","a"),stringsAsFactors = F)
y <- data.frame("Key"=c("a","b","c"), "Value"=c("AT","BT","CT"),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Code
newdf <- x %>% mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(id,count)) %>%
  rename(Key=value) %>%
  left_join(y) %>%
  mutate(Value=ifelse(is.na(Value),Key,Value)) %>%
  dplyr::select(-Key) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=Value) %>%
  dplyr::select(-id)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  count X     Y     Z     R    
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1    12 AT    BT    CT    BT   
2    13 No    CT    CT    No   
3    14 BT    Yes   CT    AT
```

Comment: It worked on this example but with my actual code I am getting error on pivot_longer:Error in -x : invalid argument to unary operator any help

Comment: @DaveM You are using other data, right? could you please use `str(yourdata)` and check the variable types, also what are the names?

Comment: In my data one of the data type is int

Comment: @DaveM Maybe the `count` variable or other?